# Biokleen (biodegradable detergent) soaked into drywall

Tags: drywall, garage, mold

I have a wall that goes into a storage room in the garage. It is drywall with fiberglass insulation.
I stored a gallon of Biokleen (Biokleen All Purpose Cleaner Super Concentrated, 128 oz) and it looks like there was a leak, where about a quart of it spilled against the drywall for the past 1-2 years.
I just found it today and removed the Biokleen container, but now there are white spots all over the floor and against the bottom of the drywall. I fear mold.
I tested it with a moisture monitor and the top of the drywall is 0% moisture, while the bottom hit 96-100% moisture.

What do I do?
Should I cut the drywall out?
How do I go about cleaning this?
Will cleaning this cause mold spores to go all over the house?
Should I open up the wall, remove all insulation within a 12" radius of the wet spot, spray Mold Control/white vinegar, then re-mud?

Any helpful advice or any tips on anything I should consider is much appreciated.

This is my first home :(.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This is difficult to answer without more information, and you may need to get that more information by cutting into the wall and checking the insulation. If you're concerned about mold, wear a mask.

Comment: I should note that this was biokleen that spilled - I'm not sure if that's necessarily the same as water damage, nor am I sure that mold could grow from moisture due to biokleen? "Biokleen All Purpose Cleaner Super Concentrated"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mold is already everywhere (how do you think it gets around so quickly?) and its danger is severely overblown for most people. Scrub with a mild detergent, dry things out well, and don't worry about it. Prime with a stain blocker and paint if you like.

There's hardly a house on the planet without a little mold somewhere in it. A gallon of wet certainly didn't destroy your wall or put your health at additional risk. It's cases with massive amounts of moisture over a period of time that cause concern.

Based on your description you may simply have concentrated cleaner collected on the wall and floor. Again, scrub it up with mild detergent.

Comment: I second the crystallized/concentrated cleaner on the floor/wall - if so, just getting it wet, should dissolve the "salts", for easy cleanup.